# Social sharing with ember.js

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ember.js

I have single page app made with ember.js and I have some problems with implementing social sharing.

I need to implement into hbs template something like this:

```
<a href="http://someaddres.com?u={{model.url}}&title={{model.title}}">Link</a>
```

However when this is rendered into browser there are additional script tags concatenated within the `href` string, eventually the link works and I am redirected but instead title I get something like this:

```
<script id='metamorph-190-start' type='text/x-placeholder'></script>
MyTitle
<script id='metamorph-19...
```

Where I need just MyTitle.

More specifically I use the following hbs template for facebook sharing, the model is initialized into the router:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/login.php?next=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fsharer%2Fsharer.php%3Fs%3D100%26p%255Btitle%255D%3D{{model.title}}%26p%255Burl%255D%3D{{model.url}}%26p%255Bsummary%255D%3D{{model.summary}}%26p%255Bimages%255D%255B0%255D%3D%2540Model.EventImage%2527%253EShare&display=popup"
target="_blank">
<img src="http://www.simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/facebook_img.png" alt="Facebook" />
</a>
```

I also tried third party libraries, like janrain, ShareThis or AddThis, but with them I had initialization problems, buttons were not shown at all when placed into template, and also had problems with messages customization from the model.

Thanks,
Igor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Approach 1 - Using unbound

To get rid of the metamorph tags surrounding your model value, try using the `unbound` option which does exactly that:

```
<a href="http://someaddres.com?u={{unbound model.url}}&title={{unbound model.title}}">Link</a>
```

### Approach 2 -  Computing the URL

In the case you need the model property to be bound and reevaluating when the model changes, then a different approach might be better like for example generating the URL in the controller backing up your template.

Assuming your controller is e.g. `ApplicationController` and the links live in the correspondent `application` template then you could do the following:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  url: function() {
    var url = this.get('model.url');
    var title = this.get('model.title');
    // grab here as many properties you need from your model
    var href = 'http://someaddres.com?u=%@&title=%@'.fmt(url, title);
    return href;
  }.property('model')
});
```

And then use the computed `url` property like this in your template:

```
<a {{bind-attr href=url}} target="_blank">Link</a>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This actually doesn't work that well since this will open a new browser tab\window instead of the desired popup window you get when using the suggested js code form facebook @ https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/

Unfortunately, you also need to create an 'action' within a Ember.View (for example) that calls window.open(url,"blah","width=300,height=500")